# Karamajs only running one file

Tags: javascript, karma-mocha, gulp-karma

I'm trying to test my client-side scripts using a gulp task in Karmajs with the browserify and mocha extensions, but only one test file is being run. Here is my gulp task

```js
let Server = require('karma').Server;
gulp.task('client-test', function (done) {
    new Server({
        configFile: `${__dirname}/karma.conf.js`,
        singleRun: true
    }, done).start();
});
```

Here is my config file:

```js
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '../',
        frameworks: ['mocha', 'browserify'],
        files: [{ pattern: 'client/test/spec/**/*.js', included: true }],
        preprocessors: {
            "client/test/spec/**/*.js": ['browserify']
        },
        client: {
            mocha: {
                reporter: 'html',
                ui: 'bdd'
            }
        },
        browserify: {
            debug: true,
            transform: ['babelify', 'debowerify', 'brfs']
        },
        reporters: ['spec'],
        port: 8081,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autowatch: true,
        browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
        phantomjsLauncher: {
            exitOnResourceError: true
        }
    });
};
```

As you can see I'm using ** selectors to  get js files in all subdirectories, but when I run the task I get the following output:

```bash
> node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js "client-test"

[12:24:26] Using gulpfile ~/workspace/gulpfile.js
[12:24:26] Starting 'client-test'...
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "/home/ubuntu/workspace/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js" as it exceeds the max of "100KB".
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "/home/ubuntu/workspace/bower_components/angular/angular.js" as it exceeds the max of "100KB".
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "/home/ubuntu/workspace/bower_components/rxjs/dist/rx.all.js" as it exceeds the max of "100KB".
08 06 2016 12:24:51.273:INFO [framework.browserify]: bundle built
08 06 2016 12:24:51.334:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.22 server started at http://0.0.0.0:8081/
08 06 2016 12:24:51.362:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
08 06 2016 12:25:04.754:ERROR [phantomjs.launcher]: Fontconfig warning: ignoring C.UTF-8: not a valid language tag

08 06 2016 12:25:09.105:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket /#SqfLEWAUFbgjRpw6AAAA with id 21013769

  AuthService
    ✓ Logs in a existing user
    ✓ Registers a new user
    ✓ Checks to see if a user is already authenticated

PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 3 of 3 SUCCESS (0.152 secs / 0.041 secs)
TOTAL: 3 SUCCESS
```

Why is only one test file being run? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that when there's an error in the second file, the tests won't run at all for the second file.